# How to convert HashMap to Closure for Titan filter

Tags: groovy, titan, gremlin

I am using Gremlin 2.5.0 / Groovy 2.3.7.

I have a hashMap that contains key-value pairs of the parameters/values for which I want to filter.  For example, I have

```
[param1:val1, param2:val2:, param3:val]
```

The type of query that I want to make is:

```
g.V.filter{it.param1=='val1' && it.param2=='val2' && it.param3=='val3'}
```

Is there a straightforward Gremlin/Groovy way of using the hashMap to make the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid use of `filter` in Gremlin when possible, especially with Titan and on large scale graphs.  Use of `filter` will prevent Titan from making proper use of indices.  You should prefer use of `has` when possible.

I would attempt to build a pipeline with your `Map`:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()  
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> params = [name:'josh',age:32]               
==>name=josh
==>age=32
gremlin> pipeline = g.V();null                       
==>null
gremlin> params.each{k,v->pipeline=pipeline.has(k,v)}
==>name=josh
==>age=32
gremlin> pipeline                                    
==>v[4]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's acceptable in the filter closure, but this might work.

```
def params = [param1:'val1', param2:'val2':, param3:'val3']
g.V.filter{
    params.every {key, value ->
        it[key] == value
    }
}
```